# Full screen video is covered by taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, fullscreen

Whenever watching a video (usually Youtube on chrome, or even with VLC) in full screen, the taskbar stays in there, and it's extremely distracting, and sometimes even blocking me from certain input

<sub>I've circled some buttons that get cut off in this youtube video)</sub>

[image: taskbar covering youtube video and buttons that get cut off]

I'm on Windows 10, so far the only fix I could think of was to make my taskbar auto hide, but I don't like that since, well, it auto hides and whenever I do scroll over to click pause or anything it comes up, so it isn't really helpful for the input issue (maybe the distraction)

As for the videos that are on my hard drive etc. if I watch them in Movies & TV or WMP it works (but I really dislike them both)

---

<sup>Disclaimer: I have nothing to do with TKOR, just happens to be the video I used for this image</sup>

Comment: I found [this discussion](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/windows-10-taskbar-always-on-top-would-like-to/a39fe424-44f1-457e-8669-9f9f33e9e7e7?auth=1), that might help you...

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado Thanks, but they mention the same thing to auto-hide taskbar, which as I've mentioned A. doesn't solve B. not what I want either way

Comment: On page 7 of the discussion, an user posted a workaround... I didn't test it, since I'm not facing this issue...

Answer (score 2):

- Open Task Manager
- End the process of Explorer.exe
- Click on File->Run new task
- Type explorer.exe and hit enter
  it will solve the problem.

Comment: brilliant tysm!